# How to do error trapping in a for-loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, error-handling

Hello I was wondering anyone knew how to do error trapping in a "for" loop
I have my loop working and a way to recognize that an invalid number was entered but the invalid number still takes up one of the places in my array

I was wondering if there was a way to get the program to ignore or throw out the invalid input.

```
        //for loop to collect quiz scores
for (Quiz=0 ; Quiz < 4; Quiz++) //loop to input and add 4 quiz grades
{
    cout << "Enter grade for Quiz " << QuizN++ << " ";  //output to screen 
    cin >> Qscore[Quiz];    //array in action taking scores inputted and assigning it a position inside the array

    if (Qscore[Quiz] >= 0 && Qscore[Quiz] <= 10)
        QTotal = QTotal + Qscore[Quiz];
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 10" << endl;
        QuizN--;
    }
```

Comment: If needed I can post the entire program

Comment: A simple way might be `Quiz--;`  in else

Comment: ssnobody thank you that actually was a simple fix thank you I feel dumb for not seeing that

Comment: No problem, I think it's worth clarifying the difference between Quiz and QuizN. Would it be better to have just one variable and simply output `Quiz+ 1` in the `cout`. QuizN doesn't seem to be used other than for display.

Comment: Yes actually I just tested it a few times just putting `Quiz+1` does the same thing. QuizN's function was just to output which quiz score needed to be inputted. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to ssnobody

The solution I found that fixed my problem was to add `Quiz--`into the else statement

```
        //for loop to collect quiz scores
for (Quiz=0 ; Quiz < 4; Quiz++) //loop to input and add 4 quiz grades
{
    cout << "Enter grade for Quiz " << QuizN++ << " ";  //output to screen 
    cin >> Qscore[Quiz];    //array in action taking scores inputted and assigning it a position inside the array

    if (Qscore[Quiz] >= 0 && Qscore[Quiz] <= 10)
        QTotal = QTotal + Qscore[Quiz];
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 10" << endl;
        QuizN--;
        Quiz--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Quiz = 0; Quiz < 4;) //loop to input and add 4 quiz grades
{
    cout << "Enter grade for Quiz " << Quiz+1 << " ";  //output to screen 
    cin >> Qscore[Quiz];    //array in action taking scores inputted and assigning it a position inside the array

    if ((Qscore[Quiz] >= 0) && (Qscore[Quiz] <= 10))
    {
        QTotal += Qscore[Quiz];
        ++Quiz;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 10" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: it needs to be with a for-loop as much as I would rather use a while-loop

Comment: Why would you be *required* to use a `for` loop? There is no functional difference between `for` and `while`. But in any case, I have changed my answer to a `for` loop (and yes, what I have shown is valid - you can omit parameters of a `for` loop as long as the semicolons are in place).

Comment: It is for a homework assignment and the part of the program I posted requires the use of a for-loop

Comment: Unless you are studying a chapter/tutorial that is specifically about `for` loops, then nothing should ever *require* a `for` loop over a `while` loop, as they both do basically the same thing, just with differences in syntax. As you already know, a `for` loop can be written in terms of a `while` loop. It is usually more a matter of personal choice rather than of actual functionality one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
//for loop to collect quiz scores
for (Quiz=0 ; Quiz < 4; Quiz++) //loop to input and add 4 quiz grades
{
    cout << "Enter grade for Quiz " << QuizN << " ";  //output to screen 
    cin >> score;  // Save the entered score

    // Test to see if the score is valid
    if (score >= 0 && score <= 10) {
        // If the score is valid, add it into the array and update the total
        Qscore[QuizN] = score;
        QTotal = QTotal + score;
        QuizN++;
    } else {
        cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 10" << endl;
    }
}
```

- Updated to use QuizN as the array index, thank you

Comment: If you don't decrement `Quiz` on bad input then they'll still have an empty position in the array.

Comment: The QuizN is meant to represent which quiz the user is inputing the quiz for such as Quiz 1 Quiz 2 Quiz 3